# Github pull requests, when I'm using a private git server

Tags: git, github

I have a private git repository.  I set it as origin, added a remote of a github repository, pulled from github, and pushed into my origin.

This way, I can make changes not wanted in the main project, and share them among my other development machines.

When I do make changes I want to share with the main github project, does this mean I have to have 3 remotes?

1 - My private git repository

2 - The original github repository

3 - The original github repository, forked into my github account

(That is, assuming I do NOT have direct write access to the original github repository.)

Or, can I somehow get rid of #3 above?  Can I send pull requests straight to the original github repository, or do I have to have one hosted there?  Can I somehow give access to github's servers to my private git server, and send pull requests that way?

I can't think of how a git hook would work.  If I got rid of repository #3 above, I couldn't have my private git repository have a hook to automatically send to the original github repository, because that would send even my intended to be private changes... Unless there's some way to invoke a hook selectively.

Comment: Are you trying to push some commits to a github repository?
I don't use github but it should be possible.
On my private git server, I sometimes have to **git config receivedenyCurrentBranch ignore** to accept incoming commits.

Comment: And for your hook problem, could this link help?
http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your definition of "private". If by "private" you mean "accessible only by you", then #3 is necessary, it's the only place where you can write and upstream can read.

If by "private", you mean "I'm the only user, but it's accessible read-only to upstream", then you can push your code there and request a pull to the upstream developers. *But*, you won't be able to use GitHub's pull-request mechanism (actually, Git is decentralized but *GitHub* is a rather centralized solution). You can just send an email to them requesting a pull (possibly using `git request-pull`).

You can setup #3 as an automatic mirror of your private repository. Just configure a post-receive hook on your private server that pushes to GitHub whenever a push is received on one branch you want to mirror. Or just set an alias that would run something like `git push private && git push github`.

Comment: Hadn't thought of the idea of a mirror I can ignore, except to make pull requests.  I like that idea.  If I wanted to skip that idea, though, is there a way I can open up my server but keep it locked down so it meets your definition of "I'm the only user, but it's accessible read-only to github"?  (And noy read-only to non-github people.)  Would I restrict my git server (or maybe firewall) to allow accesses from IPs with reverse lookups of *.github.com?  Or, if I initiate a `git request pull` does that give a "token" for github.com to use, but deny others?

Comment: `git request-pull` just gives you a well-formated email, no permission change or so. I wrote "upstream", not "github": that would be the machine of developers you want to send code to, not github.